# Как добавить элементы в ActionBar

Tags: android

**Объясните** В рамках того же проекта создала активити, унаследовалась от ActionBarActivity, в манифесте поставила для этой активити android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat". И в эту активити нормально добавляются элементы. Почему?!)))

**Важно:** у меня все элементы добавляются в меню в виде списка, как будто у них по дефолту стоит свойство showAsAction:never

При создании проекта сгенерировался файл меню для action bar. Пытаюсь добавить иконки, но ничего не получается, не могу заменить иконку настроек (справа сверху)
Все новые item'ы добавляются в меню, которое открывается при клике на кнопку "настроек"

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".MainActivity">
<item android:id="@+id/action_settings" android:title="@string/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100" app:showAsAction="never"  />
```

Это автоматически сгенерированный файл. Стандартно добавляю элементы

Но что-то ничего не выходит. В чём может быть дело?

Может что-то в стилях не то?

Манифест:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.ReserachActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.ArticleActivity"
        android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarThemeTransparent">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.AuthorActivity">
    </activity>
</application>
```

Стили:
    

    
    
        @style/MyActionBar
        @style/MyActionBarTabs
        @style/MyTheme.ActionBar.TabText
        @style/MyTheme.ActionBar.TabBar

```
<!-- ActionBar styles -->
<style name="MyActionBar"
    parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">@color/valencia</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTitleText</item>
</style>

<!-- ActionBar title text -->
<style name="MyActionBarTitleText"
    parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>

<!-- ActionBar tabs styles -->
<style name="MyActionBarTabs"
    parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabView">
    <!-- tab indicator -->
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_tab_indicator</item>
</style>

<style name="MyTheme.ActionBar.TabText" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabText">
    <!-- This is a PURPLE text color when selected and a WHITE color otherwise -->
    <item name="android:textColor">@drawable/actionbar_tab_text_indicator</item>
</style>

<style name="MyTheme.ActionBar.TabBar" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabBar">
    <!-- This is an ORANGE background -->
    <item name="android:background">@color/outerspace</item>
</style>

<!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
<style name="CustomActionBarThemeTransparent"
    parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
</style>

<!-- ActionBar styles -->
<style name="TransparentActionBar"
    parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">@color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTitleText</item>
</style>
```

Comment: У натсроек app:showAsAction="never" но настройки отображаются.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вы хотите заменить стандартные три точки (**overflow** icon) то вам надо в разметке меню указать один корневой тег **item** с **app:showAsAction="always"**. См. пример (тег с id **action_settings_all**).

Далее, если хотите при нажатии по нему выводить список пунктов, то пихайте их внутрь первого тега, обернув тегом **menu**  и тоже указав **app:showAsAction="always"**

Если хотите ещё в **ActionBar** пунктов слева от заменённого **overflow** то добавляйте на тот же уровень, где находится ваша замена **overflow** (в примере см id **action_search**), также с **app:showAsAction="always"** и **android:orderInCategory** меньшим, чем у первого (основного) **item**.

**Важно** не использовать в этом случае **app:showAsAction="ifRoom"** или **never** для элементов на одном уровне с основным. Ибо в этом случае они могут (будут) спрятаны в стандартный **overflow**, коий появится справа от вашей его замены. Т.е. **overflow** появляется автоматически при наличии менюшек, не влезающий в ActionBar.

---

Пример разметки:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings_all"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:orderInCategory="200"
        android:title="@string/hello_world"
        app:showAsAction="always">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/action_settings"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:orderInCategory="200"
                android:title="@string/hello_world"
                app:showAsAction="always">
            </item>

            <group
                android:id="@+id/theme"
                android:checkableBehavior="single" >
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/theme_dark"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                    android:orderInCategory="220"
                    android:title="@string/hello_world"
                    app:showAsAction="always"/>
            </group>
        </menu>
    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:title="@string/hello_world"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"/>
</menu>
```

Comment: В том то и дело, что выводится только кнопка со стандартной иконкой, хотя скопировала полностью вашу разметку, задала последнему элементу меньший  android:orderInCategory, app:showAsAction="always"

Comment: Подменю появляется нормальное, согласно разметке, а дополнительные кнопки на ActionBar не появляются(((

Comment: Не связано ли это с тем, что я наследую активити от import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity?

Comment: Добавила Манифест и файл со стилями.

Comment: @Nina_slon, вроде бы от AppCompat нужно наследоваться, если библиотеку совместимости использовать.

Comment: @Nina_slon, да, поддерживаю коммент выше. Попробуйте расширять ваши активити от AppCompatActivity из последней версии support-lib, коя в этом, вроде, месяце как раз это добавила.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно к итему добавить аттрибут showAsAction="ifRoom".

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >
    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
          android:title="@string/action_search"
          yourapp:showAsAction="ifRoom"  />
    ...
</menu>
```

Comment: не получается, даже если выставить атрибут  allways

Comment: @Nina_slon, а можете xml меню показать?